# How to SELECT the total values from a column in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sum

Here's what I'm currently using:

```
$query = mysql_query(" SELECT vote_count FROM votes ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {    
    $total_votes += $row['vote_count'];
}

echo $total_votes;
```

Is there a more concise way, perhaps in the query itself without having to use the while loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [MySQL sum function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) and get the sum from MySQL itself:

```
SELECT sum(vote_count) AS vote_count_sum FROM votes
```

Fetch the single row that the query produces in `$row` and `$row['vote_count_sum']` will have the total.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM( vote_count ) AS vote_summary FROM votes
```